# How do I create queries to SQL Server tables via Visual Studio when no knowledge about SQL nor Linq?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Let´s be frank, my knowledge regarding SQL language is very low.

Nevertheless, my boss gave me the task to build a database application using the following tools: SQL Server and Visual Studio 2008; C#. I use the VS DataSet as a local mirror of the SQL Server.

And let´s be frank again, my understanding of the VS Query builder is also very small, I´m finding it quite confusing, actually. So no help to find from Query builder.

And my knowledge of Linq is even lower...

*Perhaps I should mention that the deadline for the project is "aggressively" set, so I have no chance to learn enough about these things during the project. And I´m a bit stupid too, which is no help when it comes to challenges like this (on other occations it might be quite useful though)*

**With these permissions, what should I do (except for killing myself or retire) to be able to query my tables in a sufficient way?**

Comment: Nope, I assure you I´m not a troll. Things like this actually occur. Best regards

Comment: what is your table structure and what do u want to query?

Comment: It´s about "people resource handling", and for example I want to query when people are ore not are on vacation, to be able to know if they are possible to allocate for certain tasks or not.
Let´s say person A has a vacation start date 20 July and vacation end date 27 July, he/she should not be counted as a possible resource if allocation is to be made during that particular period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **MS Access**:

1. Start up Access, create a new DB.
2. Import your SQL Server DB to your new Access DB.
3. Select Create tab -> Query Wizard -> Simple Query Wizard (and it IS simple to use).
4. When the query is created, you can use the SQL code in your original SQL Server based application - but as SQL Server and Access aren´t 100% aligned, you might need to do some adjustments - google it up. [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917601.aspx) is however a good page that will help you out.

*Bonus is that it´s a good way to learn SQL "on the fly".*

Answer (score 2):

Start learning. Look for another job at the same time. Obviously your boss is an idiot - giving you tasks to be not qualified for (or the story is a little different - would not be the first "specialist" trying to find employment that is clueless).

Sorry, I really dont know what else to say here - if yo do not know how to do your job, learn. If that does not work, then you can not do your task. Simple like that.

SQL Query takes a day to get started (on a beginner level). If you do not have this time - get your boss hire someone who has the knowledge.

Comment: Thanks TomTom, I see your point. Though I will not set accept on this answer - cause the permissions are set, and the job must be done.

Comment: THis is irrelevant. The point CAN NOT BE DONE. You lack the skill and the time. The job is not doable like that. Get an intro SQL book - that should help, but unless you pick up some skills, it wont work. Your boss may think different - reality does not care about his obvious delusions.

Comment: I can´t argue with you, as you are right. But I know that everything can be solved, with some creative outside-the-box thinking and good tips. At least I hope so ;-)

Comment: @Kent, ok, that's good (thinking out of the box), but you phrased the question like this: 'I can not acquire required skills to accomplish the task. Given that as a limitation, how could I accomplish the task?'. Maybe if you rephrased the question, explained what the application is about, what is the size of it, how much time you have and what previous experience you have you might get better suggestions (nothing wrong in posting all the requirements you have). This way, I am prone to agree with TomTom.

Comment: @Unreason, yes, I think that my question might be a bit provocative as it shows up a great portion of ignorance and maybe stupidity too, and it really seems to be a built-in contradiction in the quoute you made. Contradiction from my part, that is. However...

Answer (score 0):

keep a c# reference book handy. Also a book on sql or you can use sql books online. You can always google for your specific problem or use a forum to get answers. Be optimistic, quit whining and get to your task. All the best.

Comment: C# reference is on my desk, but an SQL book certainly would do too!

Answer (score 0):

what type of task you want to do in SQL ? define in Detail.
and start working on the sql it's easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

there is a visual query designer in visual studio. that might be helpful. Open up server explorer, right click and existing database connection or create a new one and then right click to select 'New Query'.

In the query designer, you can add table and visually add conditions for joins, aggregates etc. and see the query being formed.

Comment: That´s a good tip! If I had the power I should set your answer as useful.

Comment: OK, I´ve created a query that way, and it automatically gets the name Query1:Query... Now, how can I use it? I can´t see it anywhere else than in the tab. Right clicking it and selecting properties, the name is read-only. A workaround is to go to DataSet.xsd, Add->TableAdapter and copy/paste the SQL query code from Query1:Query to the TableAdapter SQL field - but there must be a better way?